# Best practice of Spring Security with user details storage in microservices

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, microservices, restful-authentication

What is the best practice of using spring security with storage of user details, roles user authentication and authorization for microservices in production environment?

Answer (score 2):

One of the best practice to use Spring Security on a microservice architecture is to use the OAuth2 mechanism with JWT tokens.

Since the microservices are stateless, the JWT tokens provides a way to identify the user information. This includes roles, username, email or any other information that you might consider useful.

For this mechanism, you will need an Authentication Server. You can implement your own with [Spring Cloud Security](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-security) or you can also use an existent Identity Management tool that supports OAuth2 (like [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) for example).

The Authentication Server can authenticate the users (with a database or an active directory) and provide them a JWT token (that contains the user information) that the clients will use to invoke the microservices.

For more information about JWT, please check [this](https://jwt.io).

Each microservice is responsible to validate the incoming token. For this you can ask the Authentication Server to validate the token or you can use a JWK. The last one works like a certificate that the token was emited by the Authentication Server and saves an extra request to it (the validation is done only on the microservice).

This blog post explains this with more details: https://ordina-jworks.github.io/microservices/2017/09/26/Secure-your-architecture-part1.html

If you don't need the microservices to identify the user information, you can use OAuth2 without JWT. Which it works in the same way, but with a simple generated token.